# How to check nvidia-docker version?

Tags: docker, nvidia

I have tried `nvidia-docker --version`, but it seems just showing docker's version.
After some investigation of official documents, I could not find any information about this.

How to check `nvidia-docker` 's version?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's better to use `docker version`, it gives you more details. This command works for `nvidia-docker` too, we add a single line on top of the output.

```
$ nvidia-docker version
NVIDIA Docker: 1.0.0

Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 9):

I found an answer (on Ubuntu):

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia-docker
```